# RadDateTimePicker Auto close when time selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

In RadDateTimePicker ,I am using ParseDateTimeValue event.This event will  raise when i click on Calendar.But i have to handle some conditions on when i click the Clock of RadDateTimePicker.Please help me.Is there any event for RadDateTimePicker clock?

Answer (score 0):

The **ParseDateTimeValue** event is raised when you select either a date or a time value from the drop-down pane. So you have to do your stuff right here.